# What are the odds of a specific 5 digit combination appearing within an 8 digit combination of numbers in any order/any recurrences from 0-9.

Tags: probability

My husband has received a new debit card, a 16 digit number as per standard cards, in the middle 2 blocks of 4 numbers is my specific date of birth (shown as 25/4/88) and I want to calculate what the odds of this appearing are.

Being a bank card the first 4 numbers are usually the same, e.g 4650 on this card and the one that we had before but the next 12 numbers were vastly different. As far as I know the 8 numbers (2 blocks of 4) that this appears in are always from 0-9 in a random order. It is perhaps running in a specific order (e.g card issued 4650 0000 0000 0001 etc) but I don't know that side of it.

I would really appreciate the odds of this 5 digit sequence occurring (it shows as **** ***2 5488 **** on the card, any help is appreciated :)

Comment: I was told banks don't do it random. There is an extra kind of security, for example the sum of the digits has to be divisible by $11$. So that when you make a online transaction and you accidentally put in the wrong number then they can see it is a wrong number, and not that some random stranger will be very happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{1\times 1\times 1\times 1\times 10\times 10\times 10\times 1\times 1\times 1\times 1\times 1\times 10\times 10\times 10\times 10}{1\times 1\times 1\times 1\times 10\times 10\times 10\times 10\times 10\times 10\times 10\times 10\times 10\times 10\times 10\times 10}=\frac{10^7}{10^{12}}=\frac{1}{10^5}$

$1$ in $100,000$ for this specific location, and if you account for different possible locations you should devide $100000$ by $8$, therefore it will be $1$ in $12500$.

Comment: This doesn't account for the birth date appearing in a different place  on the card (eg. ** *2 54 88 **)

Comment: Yeah! we should devide it by 8 to account for that as well! I'll edit my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Five digits in a row can take 4 different places in a 8 digits serie, then:

4 (1/10)^5 = 1 / 25,000